# What is the name of the manga in the bottom right of this picture?

Tags: toujuushi-bestialious

[image: What is the manga/anime in the bottom right?]

I was reading chapter 244 of Magi manga, and a picture on the bottom right of the magazine cover caught my interest. I am trying to figure out what manga/anime it belongs to.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have reverse googled the bottom right corner of the picture to see if I got any results with the dude there. Closest I'm getting to the answer is the website of [Shounen Sunday](http://websunday.net/jigou/) <sup>[[archive.org on 2014-12-30]](http://web.archive.org/web/20141230133848/http://websunday.net/jigou/)</sup>

If you scroll down a bit, you can see him sitting there. Searching for the title **闘獣士** on mangaupdates reveals that it is [**Toujuushi**](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?id=63645).

The cover says that it is the serialization of the 3rd episode of the story, which matches the description on mangaupdates.

Comment: I am thinking it is indeed Toujuushi after looking into it after seeing your information. Thank you very much for your efforts!
EDIT:
 I found it under the name Bestiarius as well and the date of the "3rd" episode was this year consisting of 7 chapters which leads me to conclude it is correct manga!

Comment: You found multiple chapters? The link I provided only contained 1 chapter split in 2 parts and it says it's a completed series from 2011 :-s

Comment: And yes, alternate names are: Bestiarii, Bestiarius, Toujuushi Bestialious

Comment: I am currently going off the information I found here https://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?id=63645
It seems there was the one shot and then it has just had an irregular release pace.

Comment: You might want to 'accept' his answer by clicking the tick near the up/down vote symbols , rather than making another 'answer' to the question :)

Comment: Interesting, well if you find a good website to read it, let me know. I'll add it to the answer.

Comment: I have removed the link to illegal manga reading site (please understand that we want to keep this site professional) and edit the post to include some bit of information.

Comment: @nhahtdh Sorry for putting it there, I'm still new so I didn't know it was frowned upon :-p but it's actually the only manga website I know, I don't read manga that much :-s Thanks for the edits :-)